# issue in counting down timer from 60 to 0 on 7segment

Tags: c, timer, embedded, atmega

```
   /*
T=1/8MHz=0.125us
0>>>256=32us time for 1 clock
1/32*(10^-6)
so we need 31250 clock to generate 1 sec 
for prescaling 256 we need 123 clock
*/ 


/*
123 CLOCK FOR 1 SEC 
SO 1230 CLOCK FOR 10 SEC

*/
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>


void T0delay()
{
   TCNT0 = 0;
   TCCR0 = 0x04;
   while (TIFR & (1<<TOV0)==0);
   TCNT0 = 0;
   TIFR =0x01;
}

int main(void)
{
   int counter=0;
   int i=0;
   int j=6;
   DDRC=0xff;
   DDRD=0xff;
   PORTC=i;
   PORTD=j;
   while (1) 
   {
      T0delay();
      counter++ ;
        if(counter == 123)
      {  
          i--;
          
          if(i < 0)
          {
              i = 9;
              PORTD--;
              if(PORTD == 0 & PORTC == 0 )
              {
                  PORTD =0;
                  PORTC =0;
              }
          }
          
           PORTC=i;
           
       }
   }
}
```

Port c for stepping down timer from 9 to 0 count each sec.
Behavior is not accurate as it doesn't wait whole second.
While port d for stepping down timer from 6 to 0 count each cycle (9 to 0 ) of the port c 7segment.
The behavior is not right as it counts from 6 to 0 then it displays unwanted segments.

[Schematics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Qjs.png)

Comment: You may want to state which device that you are using to help with answering the question.

Comment: I think the `&` operator in `if(PORTD == 0 & PORTC == 0 )` looks very suspicious. Do you mean `if(PORTD == 0 && PORTC == 0 )`?

Comment: @JonathonS. The device atmega 16

Comment: @Cheatah well still it doesn't make much difference

Comment: What is the point of the if test on PORTC and PORTD : if both are 0 you set them to 0 ?

Comment: What is the use of j ? Does not appear in code.

Comment: @PtitXav it does: `PORTD=j;`

Comment: Ok I see it. And what about the test that set the value to 0 if the values where 0 ?

Comment: Also counter is not resetted inside while. So it execute only once when it is 123 and never after.

Comment: @PtitXav well when i reinitialize variable counter to 0 in the while loop the timing became very fast as if there is no timer

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you need to analyze the different cases for the values that you are branching on (if statements) and how you are treating their values.

First off, `PORTD` and `PORTC` are GPIO registers which means their values are unsigned so I believe the problem with your code is right here:

```
      PORTD--;
      if(PORTD == 0 & PORTC == 0 )
      {
          PORTD =0;
          PORTC =0;
      }
```

When the `if(PORTD == 0 & PORTC == 0 )` branch is taken, `PORTD` is set to 0. The next time `if(i < 0)` is taken `PORTD` is then decremented which causes overflow, giving you the unwanted behavior you are experiencing.